# Pyramid pattern that sums numbers from previous line

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

Consider the following matrix:

```
1
1 + 1
1 + 2 + 1
1 + 3 + 3 + 1
1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1
1 + 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 1
...
```

notice that first column is populated with 1's, then:

```
matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1] + matrix[i-1][j]
```

how to implement:

```
int get(int r, int c){ 
//implement here
}
```

to read `matrix[r][c]` in an efficient way?

The first thing I thought of is :

build the matrix until row of index `r` with each row populated till at most column `c` inclusive (there is no need to go beyond because values beyond column `c` will not be used to compute `get(r,c)` whatever the value of `r` is).

Comment: google fpr binomial coefficients

Comment: You could do it recursively, but it won't be optimised

Comment: But I'm pretty sure stackoverflow is not the right website for that kind of questions.

Comment: Hmm, when I try to remember my mathematics classes, get(r,c) is the number of combinations say `r! / (c! * (r-c)!)`. What is the most efficient then depends on whether you need one single value (need 2*c multiplications and 1 division) or want the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is Pascal's triangle. 
You can find something more about it here : https://www.mathsisfun.com/pascals-triangle.html

Just as It was mentioned in comments, your get(r,c) is the number of combinations so matrix[r][c] = r! / (c! * (r-c)!)

What is more, if you want to calculate it in even more efficient way there are some faster algorithms than just multiplying all numbers for example: SplitRecursive or PrimeSwing.

Hope it helps :)